# Minor problem while loading page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jsp

I'm using the slidedeck jquery plugin which basically puts slides on my page. Everything works fine, but the problem is with the css loading part. Below these slides i have an import statement for another page. This page which i'm importing fetches quite a bit of data from the database before being completely displayed.
So whenever i open my page for a second or two the display for my page goes hay wire. The probable cause of this may be that i'm putting most of my jquery including the one for these slides in the document.onready function. So since the document is not loaded completely for that period of time slides are also not displayed. (as in they are displayed but in a weird manner......they are all over the page!!!!)
Is there some way i can make sure that my css and jquery get loaded first and then a call is made to this page which i'm importing or something like that. i just want that my display comes fine right in the beginning.

this is the slidedeck jquery plugin i'm using
slidedeck : http://www.slidedeck.com/

Comment: pranky, are you loading data using ajax and calling a external file or are you loading it directly using php that is embedded in the page to load the data from the database into the page?

Comment: no its not actually an ajax request. I'm using spring, so the page which i'm importing has a multiaction controller associated to it which is called when a request for that page comes.

Comment: oh and can it be because of the data being to much that the browser is taking time to load the page?..cause the jsp page is already converted to html when it comes to the client . is there some way i can make the js in the document.onready function to run first??

Comment: pranky, I see spring is a java based platform. I don't know java, so I'm afraid I've reached a dead end here. I'm sorry that I wasn't able to help you. I hope someone else could.

Comment: yeah i guess i should have mentioned the java n the jsps the beginning itself :P...thnks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahh i actually found a solution for my problem. Now what i'm doing is that i'm keeping the div (say id="slideDeckContainer") containing this slidedeck initially as hidden (using css `style=display:none`). Only after the page is done loading inside the `$(document).ready(function(){....});` i call `$('#slideDeckContainer`).show(); on the div. (since the `$(document).ready(function(){...})` is callled only after the page is loaded)

Definitely not the best solution but for now it works :).

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$(document).ready(function() { //code here });` you can use `$(document).load(function() { //code here});` The load function fires after everything in the selector has loaded. In this case, we are selecting the document, so this function will run only after the CSS, javascript, and DOM have finished loading. Another suggestion is to give the DOM elements that you are loading content into a defined width and a height. This way, before the loading finishes, there will be space reserved for the loading content and it won't mess up your page layout.

Comment: do u mean `$(window).load(function(){...});` instead of `$(document).load(function(){});` ??....

Comment: I imagine either one would probably work? [jquery reference](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: no actually it didn't work, i'm having the same problem with the '$(window).load(function(){...}). i guess its because my page takes a bit long to load and by the way window.load is called only after the document.ready, what i wanted was something that could have been run even before the document.ready. thanks any way